# Angle between two vectors/points

Tags: java, math, libgdx

I have the following function

```
public float getAngle(Point p2) {

    return (float) (MathUtils.radiansToDegrees * (Math.atan2(p2.y - y, p2.x - x)));
}
```

The problem I have is that the angles returned look like -20 (I would expect 20) or 50 when I would expect 310. What is the right way to get the values in the "normal" range from 0 to 359 anticlockwise?

Comment: A simple hack would be to multiply it with -1 if it's negative and subtract it from 360 otherwise. Though this would depend on which specific angle you need since as you know there are two.

Comment: why are you expecting 310? explain

Comment: The docs says `artan2` works by *"by computing an arc tangent of y/x in the range of -pi to pi"*  So I think these values should be expected.  You have a solution from David, does it work for you?

Comment: @DavidLee What do you mean it would depend?

Comment: Seems like @markspace answered it.

Comment: Side note: there’s also a function called Math.toDegrees(radians) if you don’t want to include MathUtils.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
double deg = MathUtils.radiansToDegrees * Math.atan2(p2.y - y, p2.x - x);
deg = deg > 0 ? 360 - deg : 0 - deg;
return (float) deg;
```

This will give you the degree from [0, 360) in an anticlockwise manner.

Note: using `0 - deg` instead of `-deg` is to make sure `0.0` will not be converted to `-0.0`.